# strip array from unwanted characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array as below:

```
>>>tags = ['frankie', "franki's car", 'car']
```

here I just want to replace double quotes to single quote, and remove the `apostrophe` from the array indexes.

So I expect to have something like below:

```
>>> tags
['frankie', 'frankis car', 'car']
```

any help? thanks.

Comment: What if there are multiple apostrophes? Also, why do you want this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to remove the single quotes:

```
[t.replace("'", '') for t in tags]
```

The double quotes are an artefact of how Python represents string literals; it'll use single quotes unless there is a single quote *in the string*, at which point it'll use double quotes to avoid having to use a backslash to escape that character. If you have a string with both types Python uses single quotes again and escapes any double quotes in the value:

```
>>> "No single quotes"
'No single quotes'
>>> "A single quote: '"
"A single quote: '"
>>> "Both types: \" and '"
'Both types: " and \''
```

Demo:

```
>>> tags = ['frankie', "franki's car", 'car']
>>> [t.replace("'", '') for t in tags]
['frankie', 'frankis car', 'car']
```